# "Lessons learned" vs. "learned lessons"

Tags: meaning-in-context, adjectives

What does learned function here?

> there are no regrets in life, just lessons learned.

I have three questions:

1. is "learned" here adjective by the way of past participle?
2. if it is an adjective why it didn't come before lessons?
3. could we replace "learned" with "taught"?

Comment: "Lessons learned” has become a set phrase in recent years, in the area of process improvement.

Answer (score 2):

***Lesson learned*** is a common expression. "Learned" does indeed describe "lessons," and it must come after to retain its special meaning. Lessons learned refers to things that are learned with some challenge, perhaps in a corporate or bureaucratic environment. The lessons didn't come easily to the person or organization, and so the wisdom gained is strong and likely never forgotten. The unusual inversion of the adjective and noun emphasizes that these are no ordinary lessons.

You could, of course, say ***lesson taught*** or ***taught lesson***, but (in addition to being perhaps redundant) they are not common, set phrases like ***lesson learned***.

Answer (score 2):

To add on to Ringo's correct answer:  "Learned" here functions as a [*participle*](http://www.chompchomp.com/terms/participle.htm), in this case the *past participle*, which acts like an adjective.

The inversion of the usual word order is *stylized* and *poetic*, and not normally used in everyday conversation.  It is more common in such things as stories, speeches, and [aphorisms](http://www.learnersdictionary.com/definition/aphorism).

Other examples of participles:

> They say money **earned** is better than money **found**, but I'll take what I can get.
>
> The **torn** curtains streamed out from the **broken** window.
>
> With **drawn** sword, he crept into the room where the **sleeping** princess lay.